# Convert Utf-16 to UTF-8 strings with data losing using Java

Tags: java, mysql, encoding, utf-8

I have to insert text which 99,9% is **UTF-8** but have 0.01% **UTF-16** characters. Sо when I try to save it in my **Mysql** databse using **Hibernate** and **Spring** an exception occured. I can even remove these chars there is no problem, so I want to convert all my text in UTF-8 and save to my database with data losing, so the problem chars to be removed. I tried

```
  String string = " Devil Emoji";
  byte[] converttoBytes = string.getBytes("UTF-16");

  string = new String(converttoBytes, "UTF-8");
  System.out.println(string);
```

But nothing happens.

```
 Devil Emoji
```

Is there any external library in order to do that?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. UTF-8 and UTF-16 are not characters, they are encodings of unicode codepoints (characters). It is extremely unusual (and thus very unlikely) that you have characters in UTF-8 with some UTF-16 mixed in. And UTF-8 can support all characters supported as UTF-16 (even those that UTF-16 only supports by 'dirty' hacks). You might want to describe your real problem. By the sound of it, your MySQL database is `utf8` and not `utf8mb4`, so you can't store some of the higher planes of unicode, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html

Comment: Did you mean **data loosening**?

Comment: Yes. utf8mb4 must be but it is not in my Mysql. I do not want to increase the size of the DB just because some chars which I do not need. So for that reason I want to remove them.

Comment: To quote from the documentation _"Tip: To save space with utf8mb4, use VARCHAR instead of CHAR."_

Comment: OK.BUt can I change the type without losing the whole table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably has nothing to do with UTF-16.  It's hex is `F09F9888`.  Notice that that is 4 bytes.  Also notice that that is a UTF-8 encoding, not a "Unicode" encoding:  `U+1F608` or `\u1F608`.  `UTF-16` would be none of the above.  [*More (scarfboy)*](http://unicode.scarfboy.com/?s=U%2b1F608).

MySQL's `utf8` handles only 3-byte (or shorter) UTF-8 characters.  MySQL's `utf8mb4` also handles 4-byte characters like that little devil.

You need to change the `CHARACTER SET` of the column you are storing him into.  And you need to establish that your connection is `charset=UTF-8`.

Note:  things outside MySQL call it `UTF-8`, but MySQL calls it `utf8mb4`.

Comment: I see my wrong it is not UTF-16 that is why the result is wrong whey try to convert from UTF-16 to UTF-8 is some chineese char.

Answer (score 1):

String holds Unicode in java, so all scripts can be combined.

```
byte[] converttoBytes = string.getBytes("UTF-16");
```

These bytes are binary data, but actually used to store text, encoded in UTF-16.

```
string = new String(converttoBytes, "UTF-8");
```

Now String thinks that the bytes represent text encoding in UTF-8, and converts those. This is wrong.

Now to detect the encoding, either UTF-8 or UTF-16, then that should best be done on bytes, not String, as that String then has an erroneous conversion with possible loss.

As UTF-8 has the most strict format of both, we'll check that one.
Also UTF-16 has a byte 0 for ASCII, that almost never occurs in normal text.

So something like

```
public static String string(byte[] bytes) {
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
    CharsetDecoder decoder = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.newDecoder();
    decoder.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPORT);
    decoder.onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPORT);
    try {
        String s = decoder.decode(buffer).toString();
        if (!s.contains("\u0000")) { // Could be UTF-16
            return s;
        }
    } catch (CharacterCodingException e) { // Error in UTF-8
    }
    return new String(bytes, "UTF-16LE");
}
```

If you only have a String (for instance from the database), then

```
       if (!s.contains("\u0000")) { // Could be UTF-16
           s = new String(s.getBytes("Windows-1252"), "UTF-16LE");
       }
```

might work or make a larger mess.